# How to draw a star graph quiver using tikzcd in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-cd

[image]

I would like to draw a star graph quiver using `tikzcd` in LaTeX.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a just do it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Without `tikz-cd`, sorry.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \X [count=\Y]in {1,2,3,4,5,r-2,r-1,r}
 {\unless\ifnum\Y=5
  \draw[<-,shorten <=5pt] (0,0) -- node[auto] {$a_{\X}$}(135-\Y*45:pi) 
   node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,label=135-45*\Y:$\X$]{};
 \fi}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]